# Filtering a column on Dash dataTable based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am very new to Dash. I have made a dataTable that includes several columns. These columns can be filtered and sorted. However, one problem with the filtering is that I cannot filter based on a list (like pandas *.loc*) e.g. if I want to filter the countries based on a list (say, ['India', 'United States']), the filter does not work. I have previously checked the advanced filtering [here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/filtering) and found that I can use || operators; however,this would not be a good choice if the list is more than 4 or 5.

Here's the code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='heading-users', children='Users\' Country details', style={
             'textAlign': 'center', 'font-family': 'Helvetica'}),
    dash_table.DataTable(                                               # users
        id='datatable-users',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current=0,
        page_size=20,
        export_format='csv'
    ),
    html.Div(id='datatable-users-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-users-container', "children"),
    Input('datatable-users', "derived_virtual_data"),
    Input('datatable-users', "derived_virtual_selected_rows"))
def update_graphs(rows, derived_virtual_selected_rows):
    if derived_virtual_selected_rows is None:
        derived_virtual_selected_rows = []

    dff = df if rows is None else pd.DataFrame(rows)

    colors = ['#7FDBFF' if i in derived_virtual_selected_rows else '#0074D9'
              for i in range(len(dff))]

    return [
        dcc.Graph(
            id=column,
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": dff["country"],
                        "y": dff[column],
                        "type": "bar",
                        "marker": {"color": colors},
                    }
                ],
                "layout": {
                    "xaxis": {"automargin": True},
                    "yaxis": {
                        "automargin": True,
                        "title": {"text": column}
                    },
                    "height": 250,
                    "margin": {"t": 10, "l": 10, "r": 10},
                },
            },
        )
        # check if column exists - user may have deleted it
        # If `column.deletable=False`, then you don't
        # need to do this check.
        for column in ["pop", "lifeExp", "gdpPercap"] if column in dff
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From that link - The 'native' filter function doesn't support 'OR' operations within a single column.  Assign filter_action="custom" then create a callback to update the table children.  See the 'Back-End Filtering section of that link.

You'll need to grab the filter query string in a callback and decompose to extract the column name and query string. With that you can query the pandas dataframe and return the results in a callback.  I don't have the code for "OR" functionality but found some I used that can query pandas once you have the input values

```
def filter_df(df, filter_column, value_list):
    conditions = []
    for val in value_list:
        conditions.append(f'{filter_column} == "{val}"')
    query = ' or '.join(conditions)
    print(f'querying with: {query}')
    return df.query(query_expr)


filter_df(df, 'country', ['Albania', 'Algeria'])
```

Comment: Hi @max thank you for contributing to Stackoverflow and to the Plotly Dash community. I'm the Plotly Community Manager, Adam